# Dependency injection container? What does it do?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have been reading up on DI and it seems like a simple enough concept. What I don't get is the container. Let’s say for a moment that I want to create my own container. Verbs like "detect" are used and I don't get how the container "detects" that a new dependent object was created and know to inject it's dependencies. To me it seems like the container is a glorified factory.

Can any one explain how a container is actually implemented, or maybe point me to a resource?

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is taken from [Windsor documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx)

> **Inversion of Control**
>
> Inversion of Control is a principle used by frameworks as a way to
>   allow developers to extend the framework or create applications using
>   it. The basic idea is that the framework is aware of the programmer's
>   objects and makes invocations on them.
>
> This is the opposite of using an API, where the developer's code makes
>   the invocations to the API code. Hence, frameworks invert the control:
>   it is not the developer code that is in charge, instead the framework
>   makes the calls based on some stimulus.
>
> You have probably been in situations where you have developed under
>   the light of this principle, even though you were not aware of it.
>
> **Inversion of Control Container**
>
> An Inversion of Control Container uses the principle stated above to
>   (in a nutshell) manage classes. That is, their creation, destruction,
>   lifetime, configuration, and dependencies. This way classes do not
>   need to obtain and configure the classes they depend on. This
>   dramatically reduces coupling in a system and, as a consequence,
>   simplifies reuse and testability.
>
> There is some confusion created by people that think that 'Inversion
>   of Control' is a synonym for 'Inversion of Control Container'. As
>   stated, Inversion of control is a broader principle.
>
> Often people think that it is all about "injection", and broadcast
>   that this is the primary purpose of IoC containers. In fact,
>   "injection" is a consequence, a means to decouple, not the primary
>   purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna read this book [Dependency Injection In .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/)... I have already read it, and I strongly recommend you reading it. It first gives a nice and insightful explanation on DI then shows code and patterns about real world applications of DI.

From this book, and in too few words...

```
"DI container is the technology used to support the DI technique" Page 55
```

Comment: Yes it is. Btw Mark Seeman actively paticipates on stackoverflow, you can reach him easily and ask him directly, I belieave.